# biblatex 2.0 to MacTeX package, TeX Live

Tags: biblatex, installing

I want to install the new version of `biblatex` 2.0 in the Tex Live 2011 distribution installed on my Mac. Could someone give the steps to do this?

Answer (score 3):

On a mac, this should work - say your biblatex-2.0.tds.zip is in /tmp:

1. cd ~/Library/texmf
2. unzip /tmp/biblatex-2.0.tds.zip
3. sudo texhash

This will install it in your local texmf tree. Remember to delete the installed files when you eventually upgrade to TL 2012 and install biblatex 2.0 via the TL manager.

To install biber 1.0, simply get the binary for your platform from SourceForge:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/1.0/

and put it somewhere in your path before the TL one.

Comment: I don't see texmf directory. Are you sure it should be in Library?  thanks-sushil

Comment: You can create it if it's not there.

Comment: You don't need `texhash` for the local tree with recent TeX Live releases (unless it is on a network device: not common).

Comment: I didn't know that. I've been recommending it because biblatex 2.0 has a new core file in it ...

Comment: Could you please explain the unzip /tmp/biblatex-2.0.tds.zip part in more detail? Every time I download the file I get biblatex-2.2.tds.tgz. I am not sure exactly where to put the TDS file to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Follow this instructions: http://texblog.org/2011/05/12/updating-latex-tex-live/, basically run in a terminal.</strike>

```
sudo tlmgr update --self
sudo tlmgr update biblatex
```

**EDIT**: Wrong answer. Sorry, I thought it would just work like this, but TexLive 2011 is frozen.

Comment: No, that won't work. TeX Live 2011 is now frozen, and in any case `biblatex` 2.0 is only in testing: it's not released yet so is not in TeX Live anyway.

Comment: Thats the reason I want to know how to install the testing version of biblatex2.0 with texLive 2011 mannualy.  sushil

Comment: I have the testing version of 2.0 but do not how to place it on texlive installation. Any idea?   Thanks sushil

Comment: Install it in your personal tree at ~/Library/texmf.

Comment: Dan, please consider editing the comments into your answer. With something in the direction of  "I thought it would just ... but TexLive 2011 is frozen, so ..." it could still become a useful answer!

Comment: For anyone coming here these days: using `sudo tlmgr update biblatex` does work and resolved my issue.